# "Have the chance of" or "have a chance of"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, articles

Which one is correct?

- Once you have *a* chance of reviewing the document, let me know what
  you think.
- Once you have *the* chance of reviewing the document, let me know what
  you think.

Comment: Google Books Ngram Viewer is frequently helpful in assessing the popularity of phrases such as these: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+chance+of%2Chave+the+chance+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20chance%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20the%20chance%20of%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thanks. I can see that 'have a chance of' is more frequently used. Does that mean that the first one is correct and the second one is incorrect in my example then?

Comment: I wouldn't say either of those.  I would say **Once you've had a chance to review the document**.  I would use the present perfect, because the having a chance happens before letting you know what I think.  And ["a chance to review" is much more common than "chance of reviewing".](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chance+of+reviewing%2Cchance+to+review&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchance%20of%20reviewing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchance%20to%20review%3B%2Cc0)